# How to order an external list in python

Tags: python, file, list, external

I am currently confused upon how to order an external file. I have currently got a file named 'nouns' (it is a .txt file). I want to be able to take all the values from within the file and order it by size. The higher the value, the higher it is in the list. I have tryed to do this through bubble sort.

My current problem is that I don't think that I am actually taking the nouns and inputing them into the list that I have set up within the python code.

Here's the code(Might make more sense than my english ;) ):

```
def nounValue(noun):
    return noun.rsplit('(',1)[1]

with open("nouns.txt", "r")as file:
    nouns = file.read().splitlines()

for noun in nouns:
    print(noun)

orderList = [noun]
swapped = True
print(orderList)
while swapped == True:
    swapped = False
    for i in range(len(orderList)-1):
        if orderList[i] > orderList[i+1]:
            temp = orderList[i]
            orderList[i] = orderList[i + 1]
            orderList[i + 1] = temp
            swapped = True

print (orderList)
```

Here is the file "*nouns.txt*":

```
Time,25
Year,10
People,1
Way,8
Day,6
Man,5
```

Comment: How about putting the input text as text so we can copy it?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite get that?

Comment: Don't post text in an image file.  Post text.

Comment: Ok I'll remember that for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy is a good tool for this job if you care about performance:

```
import numpy as np

dtype=[('name', object), ('score', int)]
data = np.loadtxt('nouns.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=dtype)
data.sort(order='score')
print data
```

Comment: Some of this stuff is really new to me. I mean that I'm not that advanced in python just yet. But thank-you for your help. I will make sense of it in good time. Thank-you once again.

Comment: NumPy's documentation is quite good, so I suggest simply reading the docs for loadtxt (the function) and dtype (the concept).  From there it's a simple matter of calling the array's sort() method to sort in-place by any named column.  The main advantage of using NumPy is that it has array operations implemented in C which can be very, very fast.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write your own sorting algorithm, Python already has this covered. You can also read your data much more easily:

```
with open("nouns.txt") as file:
    nouns = []
    for line in file:
        noun, count = line.split(",")
        nouns.append((int(count), noun))
```

Now you can easily sort by `count` (because it's now the first item in the tuple):

```
nouns.sort()
```

and print the results again:

```
for count, noun in nouns:
    print("{0},{1}".format(noun,count))
```

Comment: Did you mean to have another pair of parentheses in that `append` call?

Comment: @user2357112: Oh, absolutely! Thanks!

Comment: See the thing is I new about the whole "__.sort()__" that python already had but didn't think it would work as I tried it but I don't think I had split the lines correctly, so it didn't work and that's why I tried it through the route that I showed in the code above. Also I would just like to say thank-you very much for your help and thank-you for explaining the steps taken as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this will do what you want:

```
with open("nouns.txt", "r")as file:
    nouns = file.read().splitlines()

# for each line separete the noun from the value
nouns = [noun.strip().split(',') for noun in nouns]
# now cast it to an int so you can sort by it
nouns = [(x[0], int(x[1])) for x in nouns]
# sorted will do the rest
sorted_nouns = sorted(nouns, key=lambda n: n[1])
sorted_nouns_reverse = sorted(nouns, key=lambda n: n[1], reverse=True)

# you can also use list method .sort() to sort it in place
nouns.sort(key=lambda n: n[1])
print(nouns)
# and of course reversed
nouns.sort(key=lambda n: n[1], reverse=True)
print(nouns)
print(sorted_nouns, sorted_nouns_reverse)
```

Now its just a matter of saving it to a file again